# How to convert csv file to Seq[String]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have csv file (userId:int,MovieId:Int,rating:double) and I want to convert it to Seq[String].

```
val value:RDD[String] = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/data.csv")
val data: RDD[MatrixEntry] = 
      sc.parallelize(value).map {
            line => {
                  val fields = line.split(":")
                  val i = fields(0).toLong
                  val j = fields(1).toLong
                   val r = fields(2).toDouble
                  MatrixEntry(i, j,r)
            }
      }
```

I want to do something like that

```
val raw: Seq[String] = Seq("0,1,1.0", "0,3,3.0",)
```

How to convert it?

Comment: Can you provide samples for input/output @Salma? It is hard for someone to guess what kind of transformation you are looking for

Comment: ok,I edit my inputs and what I want.@AlexandrosBiratsis

Answer (score 0):

With your current implementation, you can just replace `MatrixEntry` and add `.collect.toSeq` at the end of the process, like:

```
val value:RDD[String] = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/data.csv")
val data: Seq[String] = 
      sc.parallelize(value).map {
            line => {
                  val fields = line.split(":")
                  val i = fields(0).toLong
                  val j = fields(1).toLong
                  val r = fields(2).toDouble
                  "%d,%d,%f".format(i, j, r)
            }
      }.collect().toSeq
```

Comment: thanks,but my question is How to convert csv file to Seq[String].

Comment: `data` is actually a `Seq[String]`. Not sure what do you mean by "convert csv to Seq[String]".

Comment: in first row this error appear "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] required: Seq[String]